# remove axis.ticks from some panels in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to plot y versus x for two factors f1 and f2 using the facet_wrap. I want to keep the ticks for the y axis only for the first column (representing given value of factor f2) and remove the others. Is there away to do this? I tried many ways (including scale = free_y) but no success. Below is a simple code:

```
y = rnorm(100)
x = rnorm(100)
type = rep(1:5,20)
f1 =  sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.3, 0.4) )
f2 =  sample(LETTERS[4:6], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.3, 0.4) )
df = data.frame(cbind(x, y,f1,f2, type))
df$x = as.numeric(as.character(df$x)); df$y = as.numeric(as.character(df$y))

p1 = ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, linetype = type)) +
geom_line(aes(linetype = type))+ scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "F1", "dotted", "twodash","dashed")) +
scale_size_manual(values=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0.5,0.5)) + 
geom_point(size=0.5, shape=21, fill="black")  +
labs(y="y") + 
facet_wrap( ~   f1 + f2 , ncol=3, scales = "free_y") +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.margin = unit(0.8, "lines")) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2))) +
theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(0.2,"cm")) +
theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=11)) +
theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="gray")) 
p1
```

[image] 
Questions:

How to keep the ticks for the y axis only for the first column in the left (i.e factor f2 = "D"). I know the y axis have different levels but this is not an issue for me.

many thanks

Abderrahim

Comment: If you just remove `scales = "free_y"` you get the desired behavior, with the added benefit that all of the panels have the same range shown. If the range in each panel differs, how do you expect a viewer to read the scale without labels? (Or, do you want to leave the numbers but remove the ticks, which sounds equally difficult to understand as a desire?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are actually after `facet_grid` as opposed to `facet_wrap`.

See the below:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, linetype = type)) +


geom_line(aes(linetype = type))+ scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "F1", "dotted", "twodash","dashed")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0.5,0.5)) + 
  geom_point(size=0.5, shape=21, fill="black")  +
  labs(y="y") + 
  facet_grid( f1~f2 ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.margin = unit(0.8, "lines")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2))) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(0.2,"cm")) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=11)) +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="gray")) 
p1
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks DataJack.  It looks good with facet_grid. But it makes the ylim the same in all panels which I don't want to. We can get the same thing by removing "sale = free_y" in facet_wrap as Peterson mentioned.  
Thanks

Comment: @user59262     In your question you asked to remove y axis ticks but didn't specify scales being independent. You can still use `facet_grid( f1 ~ f2 , scales = "free_y") ` and then each row will have an independent scale type `?facet_grid` into the console for more options. If you want totally independent scales and a mixture of formatting between charts then facets are probably not what you want to use.

Comment: @user59262     Try the grid and gridExtra packages for arranging multiple ggplot objects on the same page.